Why is \$e^{-j2\pi f ~t_0} \$ instead of \$e^{-j2\pi f ~(t - t_0)} \$ for time shifting in the Fourier transform?
In signal processing and the study of Fourier transforms, the time-shifting property is a fundamental concept. This property describes how a shift in the time domain of a signal affects its Fourier transform in the frequency domain.
Time-Shifting Property
If \$ x(t) \$ is a continuous-time signal with the Fourier transform \$ X(f) \$, then the time-shifted signal \$ x(t - t_0) \$ has the Fourier transform \$ X(f) e^{-j2\pi f t_0} \$.
Mathematically, if:
$$ x(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt$$
then:
$$ x(t - t_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) e^{-j2\pi f t_0}. $$
Proof
To prove this property, we start with the definition of the Fourier transform of \$ x(t - t_0) \$:
$$
x(t - t_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) = \mathcal{F}\{x(t - t_0)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t - t_0) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt
$$
I think it should follow this:
$$
x(t - t_0) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} X(f) = \mathcal{F}\{x(t - t_0)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t - t_0) e^{-j2\pi f (t - t_0)} dt
$$
Where am I wrong?

Snarky answer: Because t isn't a variable in the Fourier domain. (i.e. because X(f) simply doesn't depend on t and if you ever calculate X(f) and it looks like it does, that means you did something wrong)

I adjusted the title to (I think) better reflect the content of the question. If I got it wrong, feel free to revert my edit.

@ThePhoton What would fourier transform look like for $x(t^2 + t_0)$?

I don't know if there's any tabulated rule for that...depending what x(t) is you might be able to simplify it some other way.

Only \$x(t)\$ is being shifted, not the transform. By shifting the transform as well, the shift is essentially removed.
Let \$t^{'}=t-t_0\$. Edit: [Then the OP's last equation becomes (noting that \$dt^{'}=dt\$)]
$$
x(t^{'}) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi ft^{'}} dt^{'}=X(f)
$$
not
$$
X(f) e^{-j2\pi f t_0}
$$
as it should be
So understand that only \$x(t)\$ is being shifted, not the transform.

if you replace $t' $ with $t - t_0$.
$$
x(t^{'}) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi ft^{'}} dt^{'}=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t - t_0) e^{-j2\pi f (t-t_0)} d (t- t_0)
$$

So what is your concern? @kile

Is my formula in the comment here correct?

Let \$t^{'}=t-t_0\$. Then dt' = dt
$$
x(t^{'}) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt^{'}
$$
$$ X^{'}(f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi ft} dt^{'} $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi f (t^{'}+ t_{o})} dt^{'} $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi f (t_{0}} e^{-j2\pi f (t^{'}} dt^{'} $$
$$ = e^{-j2\pi f t_{0}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t^{'}) e^{-j2\pi ft^{'}} dt^{'} $$
$$ X^{'}(f)= e^{-j2\pi ft_{0}}  X(f) $$
This proves the time shifting property of Fourier transform. Always remember that when you are doing fourier transform, whatever the function of t, you have to integrate from -∞ to ∞ with the multiplier \$ e^{-j2\pi ft} \$ inside the integral which is not \$  e^{-j2\pi f(t-t_{0})} \$.

What would fourier transform look like for $x(t^2 - t_0)$?
?

It would be easier if you can tell what the function $ x(t^2 - t_{0}) $ is as an algebraic expression such as $ 3t^{2} +t - t_{0})  $.

Let's assume function is what you said. Can you proceed with this?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656200/fourier-transform-of-t2-discrepancy . This is a derivation for fourier transform of $ t^{2} $.
